# Google Form Document

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to automatically # a field on a Google Form? I would need the numbering to appear on the actual form and not just on the spreadsheet it ties to. The idea is so that someone could place an order, fill out the form, and give the automatically generated # to the vendor.

Please point me in the right direction if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have an item for this number and define it as required and select-from-a-list. Generate the number (somehow?) in the OnLoad trigger and populate this item. The number being the only one to select user has to select and send with the form. Bit crude solution, but workable I think.

Answer (score 0):

Better option would be to make that item a section header and populate in onload trigger as above.

Answer (score 0):

[Available types of triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers) indicates that there is no onLoad trigger within Google Forms API. However, I believe it is possible to use jQuery to search for '#' within the form and increment the value.